# Fill Nan in one specific row with the first value in dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]
I want to fill that specific row with the same value "ZARATE".

```
#list of the indexes of rows containing Nan
rows_with_nan = [index for index, row in df.iterrows() if row.isnull().any()]
print(rows_with_nan)
#output 34 just one row in this case 
if not(bool(rows_with_nan)):
  #if list not empty 
  for l in rows_with_nan:
      row= df.loc[l]
      df= df.fillna(row['berth'].iloc[0]) # the problem is here if i put fillna it will change all the missing rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

# set test data and create dataframe
data = {"col1": ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"], "col2": [None, 2, 3, None, 5], "col3": [None, 2, 3, None, 5]}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

##### If you need to replace all NaN in rows with first column value

```
df.apply(lambda x : x.fillna(value=df.iloc[:,0]))
```

[image]